# SSRS Report - get distinct count of a string in a filtered group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a filtered group inside my tablix called Counties. My report is working well and produces the results of:

```
County  PY    CY  Difference

Scott    141  143     2

Cape     90    98      8

North    78     88    10
```

I now need to obtain the distinct count of my counties. In my example, this would be 3.

I have scoured many blogs and have tried several things I have read.

I have tried using =CountDistinct(Fields!County.Value). When I put it in a line below my counties, but within the group, I get a 1 below each county name. When I put it in a line below my counties, but outside the group with =CountDistinct(Fields!County.Value, "Counties"), I get the error message "The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox487’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset." I tried putting Cint() around it too and still nothing.

I have added a new column and used the distinct count function and got a 1 for each county. That is fine until I try to add them up in the row below. I used =Sum(ReportItems!Textbox486.Value) and got the error message "The Value expression for the textrun Textbox486 uses an aggregate function on a report item. Aggregate functions can only be used on report items contained in page headers and footers."

I have a feeling this is something that will need to be done with code. Honestly, I don't know code. I have always gotten by without it, until now.

Comment: Is "Counties" also the name of your dataset?

Comment: No. My dataset name is Encounters.

Comment: Try outside the group with this expression:   =CountDistinct(Fields!County.Value, "Encounters"),

Comment: Just tried it. It gave me a distinct count of every county, not just those in my filtered group.

Comment: Can you put it in the group but not at the detail level?  In other words, a sub-total?

Comment: I don't have a details row. There is one row in the group and it produces the totals for each county. If I add a row below it but within the group, it gives me a 1 under each county name.